# C, Multidimensional arrays: array whose elements are one-dimensional arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

Does this statement make sense, from the book [*C Programming: A Modern Approach, 2nd Edition*](http://knking.com/books/c/) on page 269

> Just as the name of a one-dimensional array can be used as a pointer, so can the name of *any* array, regardless of how many dimensions it has. Some care is required, though. Consider the following array:
>
> ```
> int a[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];
> ```
>
> `a` is *not* a pointer to `a[0][0];` instead, it's a pointer to `a[0]`. **This makes more sense if we look at it from the standpoint of C, which regards `a` not as a two-dimensional array but as a one-dimensional array whose elements are one-dimensional arrays.** When used as a pointer, `a` has type `int (*) [NUM_COLS]` (pointer to an integer array of length `NUM_COLS`).

I'm confused because when I think *"array whose elements are one-dimensional arrays"* I think a [jagged-array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array), but that's not what's going on here.. This is more like a macro with pointer arithmetic?

Is this in reference to the type system and how it treats multidimensional arrays? Could any one explain this?

Comment: To understand that quote, you need a thorough understanding of the declaration `int (*ptr)[7];` which creates a pointer to an array-of-7-int. Not to be confused with `int *ptr[7];` which creates an array of 7 pointer-to-int. That distinction should have been discussed at length earlier in the book.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it makes sense, and no, it's not even talking about "ragged" or "jagged" arrays.  It's simply that when we say

```
int a[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];
```

what we're creating is an array `a`, and what it's an array of is... other arrays.  You could think of it like this:

```
        +---------------------------------------+
        | +--------+--------+--------+--------+ |
a: [0]: | |        |        |        |        | |
        | +--------+--------+--------+--------+ |
        +                                       +
        | +--------+--------+--------+--------+ |
   [1]: | |        |        |        |        | |
        | +--------+--------+--------+--------+ |
        +                                       +
        | +--------+--------+--------+--------+ |
   [2]: | |        |        |        |        | |
        | +--------+--------+--------+--------+ |
        +---------------------------------------+
```

(Here `NUM_COLS` is evidently 4, and `NUM_ROWS` is 3.)

A two- (or more) dimensional array is 100% analogous to a simple, single-dimensional array -- you just have to be careful thinking about the analogies.  If `a` is an array, then any mention of `a` in an expression where its value is needed results in a pointer to the array's first element, `&a[0]`.  So given the two-dimensional array `a` we're talking about, `a`'s value is `&a[0]` and is *a pointer to an array of `NUM_COLS` integers*.

It has to work this way, if multidimensional array subscripts are to work correctly.  If we write `a[i][j]`, that's interpreted as `(a[i])[j]`.  `a` turns into a pointer to the array's first element, as usual, but `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a + i)`, where the pointer arithmetic ends up being scaled by the size of the pointed-to element -- that is, under the hood, it's more like `*(a+ i * sizeof(*a))`.  So `sizeof(*a)` has to be `sizeof(int [NUM_COLS])`, or `NUM_COLS * sizeof(int)`.  That way `a[i]` gets you the `i`'th subarray, and then `j` can select one of the cells -- the `int`-sized cells -- of the subarray.

One final note: I've talked colloquially about "multi-dimensional arrays", but strictly speaking, and as many of the regulars here are fond of pointing out, C has no multidimensional arrays; it has only single-dimensional arrays, and what we think of as a two-dimensional array is actually, as we've seen here, a single-dimensional array whose elements happen to be other single-dimensional arrays.  (If C had true multi-dimensional arrays, the subscripts would probably look like `a[i,j]` instead of `a[i][j]`.)

---

Addendum: Despite your mention of pointer arithmetic, and my mention of pointer arithmetic, it's important to realize that *there are no pointers involved in `a`'s definition*.  Pointers arise only when we try to "take the value of" `a`, or explain how `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a + i)`.

For a data structure that does involve pointers, we could contrast the situation described by the code

```
int *a2[NUM_ROWS];
for(i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++)
    a2[i] = malloc(NUM_COLS * sizeof(int));
```

This gives us a very different memory layout:

```
    +-----+
a2: |     |     +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    |  *------->|        |        |        |        |
    |     |     +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    +-----+
    |     |     +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    |  *------->|        |        |        |        |
    |     |     +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    +-----+
    |     |     +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    |  *------->|        |        |        |        |
    |     |     +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    +-----+
```

And this is what's usually called a "ragged" or "jagged" array, since it's obviously not necessary that all the rows in this case be the same length.  Nevertheless, almost magically, the cells in the "ragged" array can also be accessed using the `a2[i][j]` notation.  And for full dynamism, we could use

```
int **a3 = malloc(NUM_ROWS * sizeof(int *));
for(i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++)
    a3[i] = malloc(NUM_COLS * sizeof(int));
```

resulting in this memory layout:

```
    +-----+
a3: |     |
    |  *  |
    |  |  |
    +--|--+
       |
       |
       V
    +-----+
    |     |     +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    |  *------->|        |        |        |        |
    |     |     +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    +-----+
    |     |     +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    |  *------->|        |        |        |        |
    |     |     +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    +-----+
    |     |     +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    |  *------->|        |        |        |        |
    |     |     +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    +-----+
```

And `a3[i][j]` works here, too.

(Of course, in real code constructing "dynamic arrays" like `a2` and `a3`, we'd have to check to make sure that `malloc` didn't return `NULL`.)

Answer (score 3):

Another way to look at it...

For any type `T`, we create an array as

```
T arr[N];
```

where `T` can be `int`, `char`, `double`, `struct foo`, whatever, and reads as “N-element array of `T`”.  It can also be *another array type*. So, instead of just `int`, suppose `T` is an *M-element array* of `int`, which we’d write as

```
int arr[N][M];
```

This reads as “`arr` is an N-element array of M-element arrays of `int`”.  This isn’t a jagged array - all the “rows” are the same size.  But it’s not exactly a 2-dimensional array, either - it is an array of arrays.  The expression `arr[i]` has an array type (`int [M]`).

This view helps us figure out pointer to array types as well.  Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type “N-element array of `T`” (`T [N]`) will be converted (“decay”) to an expression of type “pointer to `T`” (`T *`).  Again, if you replace `T` with an array type `int [M]`, then you have an expression of type “N-element array of M-element arrays of `int`” (`int [N][M]`), which “decays” to type “pointer to M-element array of `int`” (`int (*)[M]`).

Comment: We could go for the full-blow headache and pass a pointer to `arr` as (`int (**)[M]`). Good explanation.