# Array of pointers and its significance

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
int *A[10];
```

If i have the above array of pointers, can anyone explain me the significance of the declaration **A[2][3]**? and what kind of value can **A[2][3]** can store?

Comment: Without knowing what `A[2]` points at, none can answer that question.

Comment: `A[2][3]` is not a declaration.

Comment: i am asking whether A[2][3] can store an interger or address of integer ? if yes then how?

Comment: A[2][3] can store an integer

Comment: ... assuming you actually make those pointers point to something determinate and proper, which right now, they do not.

Comment: A[2][3] is LHS of assignment statement

Comment: @VidorVistrom how?

Comment: `int *A[10];` So `A` is an array of pointers to integers. `A[2]` becomes then a pointer to an integer. `A[2][3]` is then an integer. `A[2][3]` is the same as `*(A[2]+3)`.

Comment: @Osiris  will *(A[2]+3) be the 7th element?

Comment: what your doing is Undefined behaviour, accessing A[2][3].

Comment: @ParthPatel No. You have an array of pointers to integers. With `A[2]` you take the third pointer of the array (index starts with 0). `A[2][3]` takes that pointer, adds an offset of 3 and then dereferences it.

Comment: @Osiris Thank you:)

Comment: You might gain some insight from [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51737894/c-multidimensional-arrays-array-whose-elements-are-one-dimensional-arrays).

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss the concepts of array.

When we say `int A[10]`,

We mean an array of 10 integers.

When we say `int *A[10]` this means an array of 10 integer pointers.
So Each of A[0], A[1], A[2]... points to a memory location that could hold integer. 
But we need to decide the and declare the size for each of them, using say, malloc.

Say,

```
A[2]= malloc(sizeof(int)*4)
```

now A[2] points to an array of 4 integers.

So A[2][3] is now a valid integer

If didn't use malloc or some other memory allocation function, A[2][3] may not be defined and accessing such a location is **UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR**